# Parallel resistors as attack resistors

Tags: resistors

In the following portion of circuit, my teacher said that R7 and R8 are attack resistors (I don't know if this is the right word to describe this). Why those resistors are called like that, and what they do?

[image]

Comment: Well, they are not strictly in parallel. Why didn't you ask your professor why he called them that?

Comment: I have to wait 2 days until I can ask him, so I ask you. Actually I don't want an answer from you (people here), I want to read about it alone, so I want links where I can read about it

Comment: @ClaudiuM: did your teacher call them that in English or in another language?

Comment: I've never heard anything called "attack resistors" before. It sounds like a term from another language that your professor (or you) translated to English without checking if it made sense in English.

Comment: We are all struggling with the possible electrical meaning of "attack". Perhaps the context is pulse shaping or pulse detecting? "Attack" is used in context of audio *automatic gain control (AGC)* as well. The tiny schematic shown gives little help.

Comment: is in context of LVDT ( Linear Variable Differential Transformer )

Comment: May I suggest you provide more of the circuit and how the context of LVDT applies to your question.

Comment: They are load resistors, and also it makes a differential circuit.  On LS1, LS2, R8, there is a current, and on R7 is another current. Together with OP-AMP, it makes an adder, so the two currents above will be added, one of them with minus sign, and another with plus sign. Is differential application.

Answer (score 1):

> attack resistors ... Why those resistors are called like that

They aren't.  That's not a standard name describing resistors in a particular use.  Perhaps that name makes sense in the specific context of what this circuit does, but we can't comment on that since you haven't told us anything about it.

Comment: The only relevant meaning I can think of is to control the "attack" in an analogue synthesiser.

Comment: Audio applications also occurred to me, but there is no way to tell from a schematic snippet out of context. Even if they were part of a synthesizer, those resistors probably wouldn't actually have a standardized name. (in the same way that the opamp wouldn't be an attack opamp)

Comment: @Simon: Yes, I thought of the attack portion of the audio amplitude profile of a sound too, but we have no context to decide whether that applies here.  Even then, calling them "attack resistors" would be a stretch, or very localized within that design group, or whatever.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what you think is wrong.